# Avoid passing data through multiple child components and caching redundant data in Angular 2

Tags: angular, reactivex

As far as I understood, there are 2 ways of distributing my data from external asynchronous web API calls to my components:

- Passing it from root element to my nested child components
- Through method calls from a service

I have a root app component with some dynamically created divs that are showing content and controls to switch back and forward to see different data. That forward and backward switching is implemented by an index number that my controls are controlling.

**My first approach** was to split the object data in my root component and pass it to my custom components. Something like this:

```html
<controls></controls>
<div class="data-container" *ngFor="let data of data; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="i === contentIndex">
    <general-information [generalInfo]="data.generalInformation"></general-information>
    <status-lights-container [statusInfo]="data.statusInformation"></status-lights-container>
    <textfields [textfields]="data.textFields"></textfields>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I created a service which I call in my app component, wait for the promise and then iterate with *ngFor through my array of object data. I am passing the data to my custom components and pass the needed data. Like this:

```js
import { Data } from './models/Data';
import { StatusService } from './services/status.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  data: Data[];

  constructor(private ss: StatusService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData(): void {
    this.ss.getStatusData().then(status => { 
      this.status = status;
    });
  }
}
```

As you can see, **my app root component never used any of the data** which is now cached in an object that is only used for creating the HTML and passing the data to my other components (something that my service should do). Also passing data from component to component is laborious.

I have also the problem, that my `<status-lights-container>` is only a container, which also splits the data and passes it to other custom components. So I have even more data which is not really used and cached.

**My second approach** is to call the service function to get the data and save it in a variable in the service. Then pass the length of my data array to my root app component and create this count of component elements in my HTML.

```html
<div class="content-container" *ngFor="let index of arrayLength; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="i === contentIndex">
    <general-information [index]="index"></general-information>
    <status-lights-container [index]="index"></status-lights-container>
    <textfields [index]="index"></textfields>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
getData(): void {
 this.ss.getStatusData().then(length => { 
   this.arrayLength = length;
    });
}
```

Now I would load the data from the data array that is saved in my service into my components according to the contentIndex they are receiving.

**Begin of questions**

At the moment of `ngOnInit()` is getting fired where I am starting the web API, how do I wait for the asynchronous call getting finished in my nested components so that they know that the data is finished loading?

If I switch to another `data-container` div in my view I just change the `contentIndex` in my service from my `<controls>` component. But how is my `data-container` getting informed about this kind of change?

Is this generally a good approach? Any other suggestions?

**Things I want to achieve and avoid**

- Avoid passing data to components that are not using it (and also caching it there several times).
- Start the web API call as soon as possible to get my data from server.
- Make it as simple as possible to load and manipulate my data.

> **Edit:** This is my status.service.ts after first suggestions in the answers:

```js
import pnp from "sp-pnp-js";
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Status } from './../models/status';
import { STATUS } from "app/models/mock-status";

@Injectable()
export class StatusService {
  status: BehaviorSubject <Status[]> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

 constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getStatusData(): Observable<Status[]> {
    return this.http.get("app/models/mock-status")
      .map((res: Status[]) => res.json() as Status[])
      .catch((err: Response) => Observable.throw(console.log(err)));
  }

  setStatus(status: Status[]): void {
    this.status.next(status);
  }

  getStatus(): Observable <Status[]> {
    return this.status.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Comment: Read here about `APP_INITIALIZER` which should allow You to delay app initialziation.
https://hackernoon.com/hook-into-angular-initialization-process-add41a6b7e

Comment: `This token is still experimental` and my app is for production. And I am also not getting how this would help me distributing my data to my components...

Comment: How about using `BehaviourSubject` in your service and pull different information that are relevat to different components?

Comment: @PraveenM would you mind to post an answer with following examples: - web API call in the service and usage in the app root component - usage of the data in the child components (and how I wait for the data being loaded there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**StatusService**

```js
@Injectable()

export class StatusService {
  status: BehaviorSubject< class[] > = new BehaviourSubject(null);

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getStatusData(): Observable < class[] > {
    return this.http.get(parameters)
      .map((res: class[]) => res.json() as class[])
      .catch((err: Response) => Observable.throw(console.log(err)));
  }

  setStatus(status: class[]): void {
    this.status.next(status);
  }

  getStatus(): Observable < class[] > {
    return this.status.asObservable();
  }
}
```

**AppComponent**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  data: Data[];

  constructor(private ss: StatusService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData(): void {
    this.ss.getStatusData().subscribe((status: class[]) => {
      this.ss.setStatus(status);
    });
  }
}
```

This would start fetching the values from the service and store it in the observable. All you have to do is `Subscribe` to the data from other child components like `getData()` do and when the Behaviour subject has values it will push them to components that are subscribed to it. As a added bonus, it will store the last value for later so that if a component subscribes to is afterwards it also receives the data.

Comment: Something is wrong about this line of code `.map((res: class[]) => res.json() as class[])`. I guess I have to enter my class (Status) for `class`as you did, but it doesnt work. And it is spelled BehaviorSubject.

Comment: @FlorianLeitgeb thanks about the spelling error, I have corrected it. I was guessing what might your `service.ts` the file could be when I wrote it. So yes you need to replace the `Class[]` with the actual `Status` and if the data is not an array remove `[]`. If you could post the `service.ts` as well I can check what could cause the error.

Comment: I have added my service class in my initial post. The error message in VSCode is: `[ts]
Argument of type '(res: Status[]) => Status[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Response, index: number) => Status[]'.
  Types of parameters 'res' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'Status[]'.
      Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Response'.` And also gave you vote up for your effort. Thank you so much.

Comment: @FlorianLeitgeb This is because the information you receive from the server cannot be mapped to the `Status` class. Make sure the `Status` have the same fields as the the response and its a array or not

Comment: Sorry but I dont get it to work. Can you please give me one more example?

Comment: Could you post the `service.ts` file please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149229/discussion-between-praveen-m-and-florian-leitgeb).